# Sticky navbar dropdown not working on safari when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have a sticky navbar which has a button class "dropbtn" that when I click on it, a dropdown list is displayed. Everything works fine on windows computers and android phones, but for some strange reason, on safari browser, the button only works once, when the webpage is first loaded. As soon as I scroll down the page, it becomes unclickable and the dropdown list won't appear anymore. Can somebody please help? Thanks in advance! Btw I'm not using nor can I use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your dropdown is showing, it is just hidden due to the `overflow: hidden;` on your parent element `#navbar_reservas`.

Try removing the `overflow: hidden` or change it to `overflow: visible;` :)

Comment: Thanks will try that tomorrow and will let you know if it works!

Comment: Worked!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad to hear! :)